# Sphinx searchd issues when running on Windows Server

Tags: mysql, sphinx, config, indexer

I am using sphinx to index my content. I used it in my development environment (xampp) and it worked fine. Now I took it to the server (same config file), and it is giving me trouble.

I have a VPS Windows 2008 server with Plesk panel. I am the administrator. the problem is that when i run the indexer tool, it tells me that it found 0 docs and indexing 0 docs. So it seems like it is working fine as far as accessing the database, but it just doesn't find any docs. Does anyone have any ideas, I spent a whole day playing with the configuration and database with no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe the database table that sphinx is trying to index is empty?

Either way would suggest adding debug command line switches when you run indexer. Eg --verbose, --print-queries etc. They will probably give you a better clue where the problem lies.